# ¿Cómo ejecutar una función solo una vez por dispositivo?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    localStorage.setItem("views", "yes");
});
if (localStorage.getItem("views")){
    alert("Ya viste este taller");  
}else{
    <?php registraVista(); ?>
}
```

Si no existe el local storage `views` registre la vista con la función de php, de lo contrario salte una alerta

> "Ya visitaste este taller"

El problema está en que no importa dónde ponga la función de php, siempre se ejecuta. Agradezco sus comentarios o respuestas, si hay una forma de hacer esto más efectivo o lo estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu problema está en que el código php no está dentro de la página como si lo está el script js. El php se ejecuta en el servidor antes de servir la página para escribir lo que va en ella. Si necesitas que registrarVista() se ejecute dentro de la página debes usar ese método para escribir allí un llamado a un script js que registra la vista en localstorage.